# When I print 2 keys and 2 values out of dictionary the first key and value replaces itself with 2nd key and value

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I am learning to program in Python 3 and I am working on a project that lets you purchase tickets to a/more movies. You first add the ticket to your shopping cart which is saved in a list and then you can view the items you have in your shopping cart.

My problem is that I don't know how to print the name of the film and the price which are in a `dictionary` without replacing the first line.

```
#TODO La alegerea 3 daca scrii exit iti scrie "3" si nu inteleg de ce...
#TODO Daca nu scrii o cifra intre 1-4 la intrebarea de la meniu sa iti spuna "nu team inteles repeta"
import string


bani = [10]
punctuatie = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

cos = []

films = {
    "Finding Dory": {"age": 3, "seats": 5, "price": 3},
    "Bourne": {"age": 18, "seats": 5, "price": 4},
    "Tarzan": {"age": 15, "seats": 5, "price": 5},
    "Ghost Busters": {"age": 12, "seats": 5, "price": 6},
}
while True:
    # meniu pentru client
    meniu = "Bun venit la Cinema Fulgerul.\nTe rog sa faci o alegere tastant mai jos un numar din meniul acesta:\n1.Lista filme disponibile\n2.Bani tai\n3.Cumpara un bilet\n4.Cosul cu cumparaturi"
    print(meniu)

# intrebarea ce vrei sa alegi
    choice = int(input("Ce doresti sa acesezi, poti alege intre 1, 2, 3 sau 4: "))
    back = "Pentru a reveni la meniu tasteaza exit: "
#daca alegi 1 se va intampla urmatoarele:
    if choice == 1:
        # printeaza doar filmele din films fara age,seats,price etc.
        filme = str(list(films.keys()))
        # scoate punctuatiile din printearea filmelor de la films.keys()
        filmex = filme.translate(punctuatie)
        # printeaza filmele disponibile
        print("1.",filmex[0:12])
        print("2.",filmex[13:19])
        print("3.",filmex[20:27])
        print("4.",filmex[27:-1])
        input(back).split()
        #daca scrie exit la intrebarea daca vrea sa revina la meniu il va aduce la meniu
    elif back == "exit":
        print (meniu)
        print (choice)
        #daca alege 2 se va intampla urmatoarele:
    if choice == 2:
        # ai la dispozitie 10 dolari
        #bani = [10]
        #printeaza mesajul cu cati bani ai valabili
        print("Ai la dispozitie {}$.".format(*bani))
        input(back).split()

    if choice == 3:
        #try:
        print("Daca doresti sa vezi ce filme sunt valabile, scrie exit.")
        bilet = str(input("Ce film doresti sa vizionezi?: ").title())
        pret = films[bilet]["price"]
        cumperi = input("Doresti sa adaugi in cosul de cumparaturi {}$ (y/n)?".format(bilet)).strip().lower()
        if cumperi == "y":
            cos.insert(0, bilet)

    if choice == 4:
        def numefilm():
            print(*cos, sep="\n")
        print (*cos, "- {}$".format(films[bilet]["price"]))
        comanda = input("Doresti sa finalizezi comanda in total de: ")
```

With this code if I have 2 items in the shopping cart it prints smth like this : `Bourne Tarzan - 4$` , but I don't want that, I want it to be like:

```
Tarzan - 5$
Bourne - 4$
```

Comment: Give an issue that we can re create.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mad_ added the whole code , thought that only the part where I had the issue would've been enough. sorry.

Comment: Keep the minimal amount of code which can be recreated independently mimicking your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing out a whole list in the last `print` statement, if you're using two list of same length to generate your output (looks like it), you can do this:

You can print after a list comprehension like this:

```
statements = ['{} - {}$'.format(x, films[x]['price']) for x in cos]
print('\n'.join(statements))
```

Comment: I tried to test the code with what you provided but sadly I recieve an `TypeError`.     `statements = ['{} - {}$'.format(x, y) for x, y in zip(cos, films[bilet]['price'])]
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration`

Comment: OK, I think I misunderstood your data structure, try now?